# Append any matching cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a sheet with a bunch of items, each with an ID number, a description, the probability (1-5), and a risk value (1-5), and a status. The probability column serves as the Y axis in the matrix below, the risk column serves as the X axis. So for each (x,y) combination possible, I want the corresponding ID number and Status to append in to the correct cell in the matrix. So for example, with values where probability=1 and risk= 1, the A1 cell in the risk matrix is updated for the ID and Status of that item.

Risk Matrix
[Risk Matrix Output Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W17A.jpg)

A sample of my data:
[Small sample of cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlSCj.jpg)

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expected results?

Comment: I have updated to include my current vba code, and a photo of the "matrix" I am hoping to append values in to.

Comment: How about your actual data? From your code, it looks like you're examining data from `C2:D500`. Could you provide a subset of that data, along with what you're expecting to see for those records?

Comment: I added a pic of my data. The goal is to look through C and D, and for each case, append the ID from column A, and the staus from column E in to the corresponding matrix cell.

Comment: I also Added the expected Output in a photo

Comment: Not to be rude, but I think you ought to just remove the code that you have because it will end up just confusing anyone looking to offer a solution. You have a bit of a misconception about how `For Each` works and also the way that your loops are actually doing comparisons

Comment: I know that around here we normally chastise people for not making attempts, but I honestly think it'd be better only to show the inputs, give a really solid explanation of what you want to accomplish, and then your output.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback, I have deleted my attempt (sorry it was so messy, I'm still very new to vba). and added a hopefully more clear explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Main - You (should) Only Have To Change The Ranges of the Matrix and the Id Numbers

```
Sub main()

Dim wsMatrix                            As Worksheet
Dim wsData                              As Worksheet
Dim RiskMatrixCells                     As range
Dim idsToAppend                         As range
Dim riskMatrixAddresses                 As Variant

    Set wsMatrix = Sheets("Matrix")
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")

    Set RiskMatrixCells = wsMatrix.range("C3:G7")
    riskMatrixAddresses = GetArrayOfRangeAddresses(RiskMatrixCells)

    Set idsToAppend = wsData.range("A2:A11")
    Call AppendMatrixWithIds(riskMatrixAddresses, idsToAppend, wsMatrix)
End Sub
```

> First Function

```
Function GetArrayOfRangeAddresses(ByRef targetRng As range) As Variant()
Dim numTargetRngRows                    As Integer
Dim numTargetRngColumns                 As Integer
Dim currentCell                         As range
Dim arrayOfRangeAddresses               As Variant

    numTargetRngRows = targetRng.Rows.Count - 1
    numTargetRngColumns = targetRng.Columns.Count - 1

    ReDim arrayOfRangeAddresses(numTargetRngRows, numTargetRngColumns)
        x = 0
        y = 0
        For Each currentCell In targetRng
            arrayOfRangeAddresses(x, y) = CStr(Replace(currentCell.AddressLocal, "$", ""))
            If y = numTargetRngRows Then
                y = 0
                x = x + 1
            Else
            y = y + 1
            End If
        Next currentCell
    GetArrayOfRangeAddresses = arrayOfRangeAddresses
End Function
```

> Second Function

```
Sub AppendMatrixWithIds(ByRef matrixArray As Variant, ByVal idsToAppend As Range, ByRef ws As Worksheet)
Dim currentCell As Range
Dim prob                               As Long
Dim risk                               As Long
Dim status                             As String

    For Each currentCell In idsToAppend
        prob = currentCell.Worksheet.Cells(currentCell.Row, 3)
        risk = currentCell.Worksheet.Cells(currentCell.Row, 4)
        status = currentCell.Worksheet.Cells(currentCell.Row, 5)

        ws.Range(matrixArray(prob - 1, risk - 1)).Value = currentCell.Value + "|" + status _
        + " " + ws.Range(matrixArray(prob - 1, risk - 1)).Value
    Next currentCell
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works gloriously, thank you! however when I run it , even though It does what I want it is giving me a "subscript out of range" error at the end. not sure why this would happen. Also, the Status does not append to the cells.

Comment: remember to accept as answer if you get it going! edited to include status. dont have access to the data set rn so cant test 100%. tomorrow i can check out what is going on re the out of range error.

Comment: Excellent answer: The only thing I would suggest is you could set the `idsToAppend` programmatically, rather than hardcoding it. Something like `set idsToAppend = wsData.Range("$A$2:" & wsData.Range("$A$2").End(xlDown).Address)` not the prettiest, but that way you don't have to change the address when the data changes (and you can certainly make it prettier).

Comment: @Zack you are 100% correct, going to edit when have chance

Comment: @S.Pullman I dont have my code in front of me but are you sure that the risk / prob that you have for each ID does not go outside of the grid? max would be 5 x 5 in example given. you can expand the grid but have to resize ws.matrixRange too